# How to import and use StringUtils in tMap using Talend 3.6

Tags: talend

I understand the library http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/index.html provides a number of string functions including `StringUtils.capitalize`

In Talend OpenStudio 6.3 I have added the `tLibraryLoad` and in **basic settings** selected `commons-lang3-3.4.jar` In **advanced settings** I have `import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.*;`

in my tMap I have `StringUtils.Capitalize(row20.Forename)` assigned to a variable but I get the error `The method Capitalize(String) is undefined for the type StringUtils`

On TalendExchange there is a StringUtils available but its only for 6.2 and lower.

Whats the best and most reliable way to get access to additional string handling tools like `Capitalize` which converts a string like **MONKEY** to **Monkey**

Answer (score 1):

It seems that talend uses its own StringUtils library (routines.system), then when specifying "StringUtils", Talend does not recognize your importn and still uses its own class.

In tMap, try `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.capitalize(row20.Forename)` instead

Comment: That did stop the compilation error but the actual value was not affected by the function call

Answer (score 1):

You almost got the correct set-up in your tLibraryload but you may try to configure it as illustrated below:

**tLibraryload set-up**

[image: tlibrary_basic_set]

[image: tlibrary_adv_set]

**Tmap**

[image: tmap_config]

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make sure that you give more information and explanations on answers. Your answer is a bit cryptic with links. Also give proper descriptions for links.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try

```
StringUtils.Capitalize(row20.Forename)
```

Comment: I don't see the difference between what i have in my tMap and your suggestion

Comment: Sorry, I would say StringUtils.capitalize(row20.Forename)

Answer (score -2):

You can use StringHandling.UPCASE(row20.Forename) to convert to uppercase.
In tMap, click on "..." just where you place the expression to fill the output fields. It oppens the expression builder. Search for "StringHandling" in the categories column, then click on UPCASE and complete the expression proposed as an example by TOS.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to convert to upper case i want to use the functions in stringutils that talend doesn't include like converting upper case to proper or title case